# OROCRM Datagrid cell template ignored in DatagridListener using datagridConfig addColumn() method

Tags: datagrid, orocrm

I have an OROCRM application and there is a datagrid, needs to be extended with a column named by userNames, and intented to display data in a custom twig cell.

To maintain this i made a DataGridListener class and in it a method to extend columns:

```
/**
     * Creates specific column names for selected persons
     *
     * @param Datagrid $datagrid
     * @param array    $persons
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function addColumnsForPersons(Datagrid $datagrid, array $persons): array
    {
        $config = $datagrid->getConfig();
        $additionalColumns = [];
        foreach ($persons as $person) {
            $column = [
                        'label'         =>  $person->getName(),
                        'template'      =>  'MyBundle:Partials/Datagrid/Attendance:person_attendance.html.twig',
                        'type'          =>  'twig',
                        'frontend_type' =>  'html',
                        'data_name'     =>  'person_' . $person->getId(),
                        'data'          =>  'person_' . $person->getId(),
                        'translatable'  =>  false,
                        'editable'      =>  false,
                        'align'         =>  'middle'
                    ];

          $config->addColumn('person_' . $person->getId(), $column);
            $additionalColumns[] = 'person_' . $person->getId();
        }
        return $additionalColumns;
    }
```

I add also data for person by the following:

```
$wrapperData = $datagrid->getData();
foreach($attendancesAtDay as $attendance) {
    // This block can be changed to a workaround
    $dayData['person_' . $attendance['personid']] = (object)([
                                                              'arrival'   =>  Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d G:i:s', $attendance['arrival'])->format('H:i'),
                                                              'leave'     =>  Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d G:i:s', $attendance['leave'])->format('H:i'),
                                                              'logins'    =>  $attendance['logins'],
                                                              'worktime'  =>  gmdate('H:i', $attendance['worktime'] * 60)
                                                             ]);
}
$gridData[] = $dayData;
$wrapperData->setData($gridData);
```

The template is reachable and PHPStorm can follow its link from reference, and is the following:

```
<div>
    <div style="width:40px">
        {{  value.worktime }}
    </div>
    <div style="width:40px">

        {{  value.arrival }}
    </div>
    <div style="width:40px">
        {{  value.leave }}
    </div>
    <div style="width:40px">
        {{  value.logins }}
    </div>
</div>
```

With this method i got the columns named by person, but with empty data. With xdebug the code never goes into the template.

With some workaround if i change the block in the foreach it renders needed data.

The workaround is the following:

```
                $dayData['person_' . $attendance['personid']] = sprintf(
                    '<table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Worktime
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Arrival
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Leave
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Logins
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                %s
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                %s
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                %s
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                %s
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>',
                        gmdate('H:i', $attendance['worktime'] * 60),
                        Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d G:i:s', $attendance['arrival'])->format('H:i'),
                        Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d G:i:s', $attendance['leave'])->format('H:i'),
                        $attendance['logins']);
```

I tried to use array instead of object without success, or any error message in var/logs/dev.log .
I wanted to avoid this workaround, and wondering why don't throws error in case i added booth twig template to column and html code as data, and why doesn't runs into the cell template?
So what do i wrong?
Thanks for any help!